# When does a system of polynomial equations have infinitely many solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, computer-algebra-systems

It seems intuitively correct to say that a system of polynomial equations has finitely many solutions if there are as many equations as there are variables in the system. However, how would you prove that a system of polynomial equations with fewer equations than variables has infinitely many solutions (corresponding to the "under-determined" case in linear systems)? How would you characterize when a subset of equations "coincide" (you can combine several to get another, like linear dependence in linear systems)?

For context, I'm in the middle of an abstract algebra course, and we've just finished Chapter 7 of Dummit & Foote (though this question isn't yet directly related to the course, that's just my background knowledge).

Comment: One probably has to be a bit careful with the "fewer equations than variables implies infinite solutions" line. Take the system of equations $x+y+z+t=0,x=1,x=2$. There's fewer equations than variables but it clearly has no solutions.

Comment: This is a good point--I had assumed that in some sense, the equations are "non-conflicting" i.e. have a solution. I'm told that Hilbert's Nullstellensatz gives a way to tell whether a system has a solution or not (over the complexes, at least). Of course, there's also the issue of equations "coinciding" with each other, and it's good to see from the responses below that "dimension" can been generalized beyond the linear case.

Comment: There is an equivalent for the Nullstellensatz over the reals (and, more generally, real-closed fields), creatively named the "real Nullstellensatz". For arbitrary fields, things get more complex and start involving Galois theory.

Comment: The material here https://www.math.usm.edu/perry/old_classes/mat681sp14/gbasis_notes.pdf Theorem 11.82 might be a good source of the necessary and sufficient condition of the existence of finite many solutions to a system of multivariate polynomial equations over an algebraically closed field. This is also called strong Nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 8):

This question turns out to be deeper than it seems, since it has a much richer theory than the linear case. In particular, it's one of the questions leading to elimination theory.

To illustrate why this problem is more complex than it seems, let me give an example of system of polynomials that can have either zero, finitely many or infinitely many solutions depending on what kind of solutions you are looking for:

$$ \{ x^2-2, y^2 + z^2 \}$$

First, note that this system has no rational solutions, since there is no $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x^2 = 2$. Next, over the real numbers, the system has exactly two solutions, $x = \pm\sqrt{2}, y = z = 0$, since for any $y, z \in \mathbb{R}$ where $y \neq 0$ or $z \neq 0$, $y^2+z^2 > 0$. Finally, over the complex numbers, this system has infinitely many solutions, namely those where $x = \sqrt{2}$ and $y = i z$ or $y = -i z$.

Over the *complex numbers* (or more generally, over an algebraically closed field), one can say that we have $n$ variables and $k$ polynomials, where $k < n$, there are either no solutions or infinitely many solutions, using a more general notion of dimension (a key ingredient in this argument is Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem). Over other fields, these questions turn out to be significantly more complex.

Algorithmically, one would use Buchberger's algorithm to transform the set of polynomials into a *Gröbner Basis* (using a lexicographic term ordering), which generalizes row-echelon form. If we have $n$ variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and the Gröbner basis contains a polynomial containing only variables $x_i, \ldots, x_n$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we know that the system can have only finitely many solutions. Conversely, if the system does not contain such polynomials for one of the $i$, and the field we're interested in is algebraically closed, we know that there must be infinitely many solutions.

*Edit*: $x^2 = 2$ has two solutions, not one. Thanks @lisyarus!

Comment: Seems simple enough to me.

Comment: Can you give a more complicated example than just the sum of squares where there is no solution? I’m sure it exists but you haven’t made much ground.  If you need ideas, perhaps use a combination of odd and even powers, two equations, and a polynomial of degree 5.

Comment: There are plenty of these examples, but it depends on the ground field quite heavily. For a famous example, consider $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ - over the rational numbers, this has only a single solution, namely $x = y = z = 0$. The proof is too large to fit into a comment, though. Over the real numbers, non-solvability is closely connected to squares (although I never got into the details of this; you're looking for "real algebraic geometry" if you want to know more). Over the complex numbers, see above.

Comment: Another interesting case: looking for integer solutions of polynomial equations - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation. In particular, for this situation there cannot be an algorithm that, given a system of polynomials, will output whether that system has any solution at all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem.

Comment: Over the real numbers the system has *two* solutions, not one: $x$ can be $\pm \sqrt 2$.

Comment: @JohannesKloos There are infinitely many rational solutions to that cubic, though all satisfy $xyz=0$. The curve $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$ does have only the single solution $x=y=z=0$.

Comment: That will teach me to answer when I should be in bed... I had misremembered what "notrivial solution" means... Of course, $x^3+y^3=z^3$ has no solutions where $x, y, z \neq 0$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful! Do you have any pointers on where to look for this argument involving Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem (about whether an "under-determined" system has infinitely many or no solutions)?

Comment: This argument is really a combination of several different steps - the way I'd argue is that I'd start from the fact that "finite number of solutions" is equivalent to "dimension 0". I'd then use the fact that $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ has dimension $n$ (most easily proved using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz in the algebraically closed case; the general case follows, IIRC, using the going-up theorem), and then applying the principal ideal theorem to  show that $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\langle p_1, \ldots, p_k\rangle$ has dimension at least $n-k$. [cont.]

Comment: But I suppose there are simpler ways (see, e.g., hm2020's answer); all of this is done using standard theorems of commutative algebra. Matsamura's book is a good reference.

Answer (score 3):

Question: "However, how would you prove that a system of polynomial equations with fewer equations than variables has infinitely many solutions?"

Answer: There is a result in commutative algebra (look at the Matusumura book "Commutative ring theory", theorem 14.1, page 105) saying that if $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ is a noetherian local ring and $x_1,..,x_r$ is a system of parameters then

$$M1.\text{   }dim(A/(x_1,..,x_i))=r-i.$$

Intuitively view each element $x_i$ as an "equation" in $r$ variables, and $dim(A/(x_1,..,x_i))$ as the dimension of the "space of solutions" to the system of equations

$$M2. \text{    }x_1=\cdots =x_i=0,$$

then M1 says that the system M2 has an "infinite set of solutions" iff $i<r$.

"Intuitively" if $I:=(f_1, \cdots , f_l)\subseteq B:=k[x_1,..,x_n]$ is an ideal of polynomials in the variables $x_i$ over a field $k$, we let $A:=k[x_1,..,x_n]/I$ be the coordinate ring of the algebraic variety/scheme
defined by the set of polynomials $f_i$. The ring $A$ is a commutative unital ring reflecting properties of the "set of solutions" of the system of equations

$$M3.\text{   }f_1=\cdots =f_l=0.$$

We define $X:=Spec(A)$ as the "set of prime ideals" in the ring $A$ and give this set a topology (the Zariski topology). If the ideal $I$ is a prime ideal
it follows $X$ is an irreducible topolpogical space. The dimension of $X$
as an algebraic variety may be defined using the ring $A$: we define $dim(X):=dim(A)$ where $dim(A)$ is defined as the supremum of the set of strictly decreasing sequences of prime ideals

$$ \mathfrak{p}_r \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_1 \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \mathfrak{p}_0 \subseteq A.$$

Hence with this definition, your system of equations should have a "finite set of solutions" iff $dim(A)=0$ - hence you must calculate the dimension $dim(A)$ in your case.

Given any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$, it follows there is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}\subseteq B$ mapping to $\mathfrak{m}$, and you may consider the localization $R:=B_{\mathfrak{n}}$ which is a local ring of dimension $n$. The image $g_i$ of the generators $f_i$ generates an ideal $J \subseteq R$ and if the ideal $J$ can be generated by a regular sequence
$J=(a_1,..,a_i)$ with $i<n$ it follows $dim(R/J)=dim(A) >0$. Hence the set
of solutions to the system is not finite. I believe there are algorithms implemented on computers that solves this problem, but I have no precise reference. In general it is difficult to check if an explicit ideal is a prime ideal, and it is also difficult to construct a regular sequence for an explicit ideal $J$.

Another more elementary approach is the Noether normalization lemma: It says that there is a set of element $t_1,..,t_d \in A$ with the property that the subring

$$S:=k[t_1,..,t_d] \subseteq A$$

is a polynomial ring, $dim(A)=d$ and $S \subseteq A$ is an integral extension.

Hence $dim(A)=0$ iff $k \subseteq A$ is an integral ring extension. Hence $dim(A)=0$ iff there is a finite set of elements $a_1,..,a_k\in A$ generating $A$ as $k$-algebra where $a_i$ satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $k$. So your problem is reduced to constructing a set of integral elements $a_1,..,a_k$ generating $A$.

**Lemma.** The system M3 has a finite set of solutions iff $k \subseteq A$ is an integral ring extension iff $dim_k(A)< \infty$.

**Proof.** The first equivalence is proved above. The last equivalence follows from the fact that $A$ is finitely generated as $k$-algebra. Hence $k \subseteq A$ is an integral ring extension iff $dim_k(A)< \infty$. **QED**

**Note 1.** If you try to calculate $dim_k(A)$ "by hand" in some examples, you will find that it is a difficult problem to construct a basis for $A$ as $k$-vector space. I believe there are computer programs solving this problem.
To prove that $k \subseteq A$ is not an integral extension you must find an element $t\in A$ that generates a polynomial sub ring $k[t]\subseteq A$.

**Note 2.** If the base field $k$ is not algebraically closed, this method detects solutions in arbitrary finite extensions $k \subseteq K$. This is the "Hilbert Nullstellensatz". For a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$ it follows the extension $k \subseteq A/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension, and a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subseteq A$ corresponds to a solution to the system M3 in the field $\kappa(\mathfrak{m}):=A/\mathfrak{m}$.

**Example 1.** Let $k$ be the field of real numbers and let $f:=x^2+y^2+1\in k[x,y]$ and consider the "system"

$$S1.\text{   } f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1=0.$$

The system S1 has no real solutions but it has many (a set of dimension 1) complex solutions. Given an arbitrary real number $\theta$ and let $x:=isin(\theta), y:=icos(\theta)$ it follows

$$x^2+y^2=(isin(\theta))^2+(icos(\theta))^2=-sin^2(\theta)-cos^2(\theta)=-1$$

hence $(isin(\theta), icos(\theta))\in \mathbb{C}^2$ is a solution to S1 for any $\theta$.
The field extension $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is finite and the dimension of the ring $A:=k[x,y]/(f)$ is 1, hence the system S1 has an infinite set of solutions (in the real and complex number field). For every $(isin(\theta), icos(\theta))$ you get a well defined surjective map

$$ \phi_{\theta}: A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$

defined by $\phi_{\theta}(x):=isin(\theta), \phi_{\theta}(y):=icos(\theta)$,
and the kernel $\ker(\phi_{\theta})\subseteq A$ will be a maximal ideal. Hence solutions to S1 correspond to maximal ideals in $A$.

**Note 3.** If you work with system M3 on a computer you should know that you are studying solutions to M3 in a finite field of large characteristic. This is because a computer has a finite memory. If your system M3 is defined by polynomials with rational coefficients $\frac{a_i}{b_i}$, it follows there is a large prime $p$ not dividing any of the $b_i$'s. The computer converts the system M3 to a system over $\mathbb{F}_p:=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (or $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$). Hence if you ask the question

$$\text{"Does M3 have a finite set of solutions?"}$$

to a computer, the computer will answer:

$$\text{It always has a finite set of solutions since we are working over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$}.$$

If $k$ is a finite field and you seek solutions to M3 in $k^n$ it follows the set of solutions $S$ to M3 is a subset $S \subseteq k^n$ of $k^n$ which is a finite set, hence $S$ is trivially a finite set. In a sense:

$$\text{A computer cannot "understand infinity".}$$

**Example.** If the memory $M$ of your computer $HAL$ has $2^n$ elements for $n \geq 1$ an integer, it cannot "work" with the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ which has a countably infinite set of elements: There is no way to "embed" $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $M$ since $M$ is a finite set. There is a number $m\geq 0$ with the property that an integer $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ with more than $m$ digits cannot be stored on $HAL$. Hence if $p,q$ are two prime numbers with more than $m$ digits it follows $p,q$ and the product $pq$
cannot be calculated by $HAL$. Hence $HAL$ cannot work with very large primes. There is an infinite set of prime numbers and only a finite set of prime numbers has less than $m$ digits. Hence there is an infinite set of prime numbers that cannot be calculated by $HAL$.

Hence by "understand" I mean the following: You may always construct two prime numbers $p,q$ and ask your computer $HAL$ to calculate $pq$, and your computer will not be able to do this because it does not have enough memory.

Question: "How would you characterize when a subset of equations "coincide" (you can combine several to get another, like linear dependence in linear systems)?"

Answer: If $I:=(f_1,..,f_l)$ is an ideal generated by polynomials $f_i$ and $J:=(f_{i_1},..,f_{i_n})$ is a subset of $I$ it follows (this is a definition) $I$ and $J$ "coincide" iff they generated the same ideal in $k[x_1,..,x_n]$.

Comment: Complex answer +1

Comment: "Note 3" is false, Finite memory limits do not imply computer algebra systems can only work over finite fields. Perhaps you are thinking of constraints of some *specific* implementation (of Grobner basis algorithms?).

Comment: @BillDubuque - I have indicated what I mean when speaking about "understanding infinity". Please explain how you will implement a computer program on HAL (as discussed above) calculating $pq$ for any pair pf primes $p,q$.

Comment: That you may eventually run out of space when calculating in a some programming language's model of $\Bbb Z$ does not imply that it is actually calculating in $\Bbb F_p$ vs. $\Bbb Z.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubucue - this is a site for "amateurs" and "amateurs" are asking questions. What do you answer an "amateur" when he/she asks the question above: The memory on his computer HAL is finite and he/she wants to calculate the product $pq$ for two very large primes. The primes are so large no computer on the planet has enough memory - what does he/she do?

Comment: @BillDubuque - Let me add that he/she does not have enough money to build a large enough computer.