# Special irreducible polynomials in $k[x,y]$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Definitions:**

**(1)** $0 \neq f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is *always irreducible*, if for every $\lambda \in k$, $f+\lambda$ is irreducible in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

**(2)** $0 \neq f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is *infinitely irreducible*, if for infinitely many $\lambda \in k$, $f+\lambda$ is irreducible in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and call those $\lambda$'s for which $f+\lambda$ is irreducible  *good scalars*.

**(3)** $0 \neq f \in k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is *never irreducible*, if there exist no $\lambda \in k$ for which $f+\lambda$ is irreducible in $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

**Examples:**

**(i)** In $\mathbb{R}[x]$, $x$ is always irreducible, $x^2$ is infinitely irreducible with good scalars $\in (0,\infty)$.

**(ii)** In $\mathbb{C}[x]$, $x$ is always irreducible, $x^2$ is never irreducible.

> **Question 1:** Is it possible to somehow characterize all always irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$?
>   **Question 2:** Is there a way to distinguish between always irreducibles and infinitely irreducibles?

---

Examples of always irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are:

**(a)** $\lambda x- \mu$, where $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

**(b)** $\lambda y- \mu$, where $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

**(c)** $\lambda x + H(y)$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $H(y) \in \mathbb{C}[y]$.

**(d)** $\lambda y + H(x)$, where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $H(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

Actually, **(c)** includes **(a)** and **(d)** includes **(b)**.
If I am not wrong, **(c)** and **(d)** can be proved by [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion). One has to be careful, for example $x+y^2$, in wikipedia's notations we should take $p=x$ not $p=y$.

**(e)** By the fourth answer to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables) question, $f=g(x)-h(y)$ is irreducible when $\gcd(\deg(g),\deg(h))=1$; in particular, taking $g$ linear yields **(c)**, and taking $h$ linear yields **(d)**.

---

If I am not wrong, in $k[x,y]$:

If $(f,g)$ is an *automorphic pair*,
then $f$ (and $g$) is always irreducible, where $(f,g)$ is an automorphic pair if $k[x,y]=k[f,g]$ or, equivalently, if $(x,y) \mapsto (f,g)$ is an automorphism of $k[x,y]$.

Moreover, if $(f,g)$ is a *Jacobian pair*,
then $f$ (and $g$) is always irreducible, where $(f,g)$ is a Jacobian pair if $\operatorname{Jac}(f,g):=f_xg_y-f_yg_x$ belongs to $k-\{0\}$.
Indeed, $\frac{k[x,y]}{\langle f \rangle}$ is an integral domain (I can add an argument for this later), so $\langle f \rangle$ is a prime ideal, hence by the second link below, $f$ is irreducible. Repeat this argument for $f + \lambda$ for every $\lambda \in k$, and get that $f + \lambda$ is irreducible for every $\lambda \in k$.

---

Please see the following related questions: [Irreducibility of polynomials in two variables](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables), [What do prime ideals in $k[x,y]$ look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like), [Irreducibility of Polynomials in $k[x,y]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303681/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-kx-y).

Thank you very much! I later asked the above question in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352518/special-irreducible-polynomials-in-kx-y).

Comment: If $f\in \Bbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is irreducible then there is some $r>0$ such that for all $|a|<r$, $f+a$ is irreducible. This is because with $Z(f+a)-S(f+a)$ the vanishing set of $f+a$ minus the singular points, then $Z(f+a)-S(f+a)$ is connected, and locally this set moves continuously with $a$.

Comment: @reuns, thank you very much for your interesting comment.

Comment: @reuns, please do you have any idea how we can distinguish between always irreducibles and infinitely irreducibles? For example,  $f=y+x^3$ and $g=xy+1$; $f$ is always irreducible (example e), while $g$ is infinitely irreducible with good scalars $\mathbb{C}^{\times}=\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, oh, thank you. I will now mention this in my above question.

Comment: With $ f\in \Bbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ then $f+a$ is irreducible for some $a\in \Bbb{C}$ iff $(f+t)$ is a prime ideal of $ K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $K=\overline{\Bbb{C}(t)}$, in which case $f+a$ is irreducible for all but finitely many $a$. Moreover those $a$ can be found in term of the zeros of the discriminants in each variable. This follows from that the map sending $z$ to one of the roots of $g(z,y)\in \Bbb{C}[z][y]$ is analytic away from the $z$ where $g(z,y)$ has a double root.

Comment: @reuns, thank you for your nice comment. I am more or less familiar with its first part (until "Moreover"), but not with its second part. Please, could you slightly elaborate about it in an answer? I do not understand how to find those 'bad' scalars.