# $X^3Y+Y^3+X\in \Bbb Z_2[X,Y]$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_2[X,Y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials, multivariate-polynomial

> **Exercise.** We would like to prove that the polynomial $f(X,Y):=X^3Y+Y^3+X\in \Bbb Z_2[X,Y]$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_2[X,Y]$.

***My attempt.*** Consider $f(X,Y):=X^3Y+Y^3+X\in (\Bbb Z_2[X])[Y]$ and we are looking for a factorisation in $(\Bbb Z_2[X])[Y]$. So, say
$$Y^3+X^3Y+X=(p_1(X)Y+p_2(X))(p_3(X)Y^2+p_4(X)Y+p_5(Y)).$$
Then,
$$p_1(X)p_3(X)=1 \implies p_1(X)=p_3(X)=1,\\
p_1(X)p_5(X)+p_2(X)p_4(X)=X^3\implies p_5(X)=X^3+p_2(X)p_4(X),\\
p_2(X)p_5(X)=X \implies X^3p_2(X)+p_2^2(X)p_4(X)=X.$$
So, $p_2(X)(X^3+p_2(X))p_4(X))=X \implies \deg_X p_2(X)+\deg_X(X^3+p_2(X)p_4(X))=1$.

**Questions.**

1. Is this methogology correct? And if yes, how can we reach a contradiction?
2. Can we work with the total degree for a contradiction, like this [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/303843/326865)?
3. Any other ways to prove this?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 5):

You have another approach using *Eisenstein criterion* for the ring of polynomials $\mathbf F_2[X][Y]$ with coefficients in the P.I.D. $\mathbf F_2[X]$:

$X$  divides all coefficients of the polynomial $Y^3+X^3Y+X$, but the leading coefficient, and $X^2$ does not divide its constant term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This undoubtedly is a nice way. However, can I ask you how could we exploit the definition?

Comment: Exploit which definition?

Comment: Of the irreducible polynomials in 2 variables: $f\in K[X, Y] \setminus K$ is irreducible, if it can not be written in the form $f=gh$, for some $g, H \in K[X, Y]$ of (total) degree $\deg h, \deg g < \deg f$.

Comment: Any ideas for a definition-based proof?

Comment: Not sure what you think of with ‘definition-based’, but you can use that if it has a factor, there results a factor in $\mathbf F_2[X]/(X-1)[Y]$, i.e. $Y^3+Y+1$  has a factor in $\mathbf F_2[Y]$. Now, for degree reasons it has a linear factor, i.e. it has a root in $\mathbf F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Macaulay2 code that proves your polynomial is irreducible:

(You can run this here: http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/TryItOut/ )

> R = ZZ/2[X,Y]
>
> I = ideal(X^3 * Y + Y^3 + X)
>
> isPrime I

If you run this you get:

```
i1 : R = ZZ/2[X,Y]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : R

o2 = R

o2 : PolynomialRing

i3 : I = ideal(X^3 * Y + Y^3 + X)

            3     3
o3 = ideal(X Y + Y  + X)

o3 : Ideal of R

i4 : isPrime I

o4 = true
```